# Ignore some locations in Windbg Conditional breakpoints

Tags: windbg, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I'm trying to set a conditional hardware breakpoint on Windows Kernel-Mode in Windbg by using the following syntax :

```
ba w1 ffff802312345678 "j(@rip==ffff802387654321 || @rip==ffff802387654330) 'gc';''"
```

I used the above command in order to ignore every access to my target location (`ffff802312345678`) from `ffff802387654321` or `ffff802387654330`, so everytime access from somewhere else is taken, then I would be notified.

But the problem is, it still breaks on `ffff802387654321` or  `ffff802387654330` among the other locations.

I also read it's [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-a-conditional-breakpoint) about "**Conditional Breakpoints and Register Sign Extension**" and also test something like this:

```
ba w1 ffff802312345678 "j((@rip & 0xffffffffffffffff)=ffff802387654321 || (@rip & 0xffffffffffffffff)=ffff802387654330) 'gc';''"
```

But it still won't work.

So my question is:

- What's wrong with the above command and how can I achieve the desired
  result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `||` [MASM operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/masm-numbers-and-operators). It's `or`.

Use

```
ba w1 ffff802312345678 "j(@rip==ffff802387654321 or @rip==ffff802387654330) 'gc';''"
```

I have not reproduced your exact case, but a simpler example:

```
0:000> r rip
rip=0000000076db6fb0
0:000> j (@rip==0000000076db6fb0 || @rip==0) '.echo 5';'.echo 6"
Numeric expression missing from '| @rip==0) '.echo 5';'.echo 6"'
0:000> j (@rip==0000000076db6fb0 or @rip==0) '.echo 5';'.echo 6"
5
```

Comment: As a side note, it is possible to use `||` by using the `@c++`operator: `j (@@c++(@rip==0000000076db6fb0 || @rip==0)) '.echo 5';'.echo 6"` or switching altogether to the c++ evaluator with `.expr /s c++`.

Comment: @Neitsa: I tried that @@c++ but it didn't work. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Neitsa: `.expr /s c++` does not work either. In both cases it says "Could not resolve error at ..."

Comment: Strange :( Here's an [session example](https://gist.github.com/neitsa/8fb0f02ae084cf3012f4923763b18ebb) ; My Windbg version is `10.0.16299.15` (**not** the windbg preview).